# Can I use IF statements with a message dialog in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, confirm-dialog

So, I've been stumped on this piece of code for about a week now, I want to have the code sending an error message when the user chooses 'No' or 'Cancel' however I get an error which tells me that NO and CANCEL are not variables. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can overcome this problem?

```
int mc = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;
    int bc = JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION;

    int ch = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Select:", "Title", bc, mc);

    if (bc == NO)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry, you cannot continue without agreeing to the rules.");
    }
    else if (bc == CANCEL)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry, you cannot continue without agreeing to the rules.");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Thank you, you may continue!");
    }
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment. Use `==` to compare

Comment: And what are `NO` and `CANCEL` in your opinion?

Comment: The value of bc should be from user's input and convert its type the whatever `NO` and `CANCEL` are, then you can compare the values by using the type's function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all explained [in the JOptionPane Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

In the code that you've given, the button that you've clicked is identified by the return value from `showConfirmDialog`, which you've assigned to `ch`, not `bc`.  In your case, the  logic  should be

```
if (ch == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    ...
}
else if (ch == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much, I had it working before but it crashed on me, hopefully it doesn't do the same again!